# Fullcalendar dayRender: Cannot read property 'format' of undefined

Tags: fullcalendar

I am working with Fullcalendar. I create events now by dragging and dropping. I want to do it with a double click on a day. I am trying to use the dayRender function but "event.start.format()" is undefined.

```
dayRender: function(event, element) {
            element.bind('dblclick', function(event,element) {  
                    var title = prompt('Event Title:', event.title, { buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false} });
                      if (title){
                        console.log(event);
                          event.title = title;
                          var start = event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:MM:SS");
                          $.ajax({
                                url: '{!!URL::route("saveCalendarEvent")!!}',
                                data: 'type=new&title='+title+'&startdate='+start+'&zone='+zone,
                                type: 'POST',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success: function(response){    
                                event.id = response.eventid;
                                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);
                                },
                                error: function(e){
                                    alert('Error processing your request: '+e.responseText);
                                }
                            });
                      }

            });
        }
```

The error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'format' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

The dayRender parameters are date and cell, not event and element:

According to the [FullCalendar Docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/dayRender/) for dayRender :

```
function( date, cell ) { }
```

So the problem is, your 'element' variable is actually a date and so 'event.start' doesn't exist thus throwing an error when you call 'event.start.format'

Comment: So what should i do now scottysmalls?

Comment: Change the function parameters first. Then in your ajax use the title from your prompt as the title and 'date' which you get from the dayRender callback. ( something like var start = date.format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:MM:SS");